# In R how to create a year vector with a simple rule

Tags: r

I have the first year as `2007`. The last year is `2021`

I need to create a character vector just like the vector bellow:

```
c("2007-2008","2007-2010","2007-2012","2007-2014","2007-2016","2007-2018","2007-2021")
```

The idea is to have: `first-year -second year`, `first-year - first-year+3`, `first-year - first-year+5`, `first-year - first-year+7`, `first-year - first-year+9`, `first-year - first-year+11`, `first-year - first-year+13` But when I have `first-year - first-year+13` and the next step is bigger than the last year (`2021`) I consider `first-year - lastyear`

In other words the difference between the last years should be at least 2 (2008....2010...2012...2014..2016...2018...2020) But once I have 2020 it will lead the next interval `2007-2021` have a difference of 1 year, if this happens I consider `2007-2018`and `2007-2021`

How can I create something like this in R?

Comment: `paste(2007, 2007 + seq(1, 13, by = 2), sep = "-")` gets you most of it, but I do not understand why you skipped 2020 and went to 2021 out of sequence.

Comment: @r2evans I skip 2020 beacause I need to maintain the difference between the last years `at least`in 2 years, if not should be 3 years

Comment: So, I should end with 2008,2010,2012,2014, 2016, 2018 , 2020, 2021....considering 2020 would make the differences between the end years to 1....i dont know if i was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
years <- c(2007, 2021)
years <- unique(sort(c(years, seq(1 + years[1], years[2], by = 2))))
years
# [1] 2007 2008 2010 2012 2014 2016 2018 2020 2021
years <- years[c(diff(years) >= 2, TRUE)]
years
# [1] 2008 2010 2012 2014 2016 2018 2021
paste(2007, years, sep = "-")
# [1] "2007-2008" "2007-2010" "2007-2012" "2007-2014" "2007-2016" "2007-2018" "2007-2021"
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea to generate the required sequence directly from `seq`

```
st <- 2007
en <- 2021

paste(st, unique(c(seq(st + 1, en - 2, 2), en)), sep = "-")
[1] "2007-2008" "2007-2010" "2007-2012" "2007-2014" "2007-2016" "2007-2018"
[7] "2007-2021"
```